# count all values on object array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to count each value on  the object array , the desired output should be  like below

```
[{
    "question": "question1",
    "USA": 2
  }, {
    "question": "question1",
    "AUS": 1
  },

  {
    "question": "question2",
    "item1": 2
  },

  {
    "question": "question2",
    "item1,item2": 1
  }, {
    "question": "question4",
    "3": 1
  }, {
    "question": "question4",
    "2": 1
  }
]
```

Below is the input I need to transform in to the above output. I  have no clue how to do with n no of question and also got issue when one question has 2 answers . sample input

```
[{"question1":"USA","question2":["item1"],"question4":2}, 
{"question1":"USA","question2":["item1"],"question4":3}, 
{"question1":"AUS","question2":["item1","item2"]}];
```

```js
let arr=[{"question1":"USA","question2":["item1"],"question4":2},{"question1":"USA","question2":["item1"],"question4":3},{"question1":"AUS","question2":["item1","item2"]}];
//console.log(arr);



function solve(list){
    var map = new Map();
    var entry = null;
    for(var item of list){
        if(!map.has(item.question1))
            map.set(item.question1, {question:'question1'});

            entry = map.get(item.question1);

        if(entry.hasOwnProperty(item.question1))
            entry[item.question1] = entry[item.question1] + 1;
        else
            entry[item.question1] = 1;
            
         
          if(!map.has(item.question2))
            map.set(item.question2, {question: 'question2'});

            entry = map.get(item.question2);

        if(entry.hasOwnProperty(item.question2))
            entry[item.question2] = entry[item.question2] + 1;
        else
            entry[item.question2] = 1;
         
    }
    return Array.from(map.values());
}
console.log(solve(arr))
```

Comment: It's not JSON - it's a normal JavaScript array of objects.

Comment: ^^ JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object or what ever data structure you like which supports a key/value structure in a nested style and collect first all items and then reder the collected tree.

This approach uses objects, because the keys are strings, this is important for an array as key. This is joint with a comma which is sufficient for this use case.

```js
var data = [{ question1: "USA", question2: ["item1"], question4: 2 }, { question1: "USA", question2: ["item1"], question4: 3 }, { question1: "AUS", question2: ["item1", "item2"] }],
    hash = data.reduce((hash, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([question, value]) => {
            var sub = hash[question] = hash[question] || Object.create(null);
            sub[value] = sub[value] || { question, [value]: 0 };
            sub[value][value]++;
        });
        return hash;
    }, Object.create(null)),
    result = Object.values(hash).reduce((r, sub) => [...r, ...Object.values(sub)], []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, obtain the countries by using `reduce`. Then use some nested `forEach` loops for the rest:

```js
const input = [{"question1":"USA","question2":["item1"],"question4":2}, 
{"question1":"USA","question2":["item1"],"question4":3}, 
{"question1":"AUS","question2":["item1","item2"]}];
const countriesOutput = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc.some(e => e[curr.question1])) {
    acc.push({ question: "question1", [curr.question1]: 1 });
  } else {
    acc.find(e => e[curr.question1])[curr.question1]++;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
let questionsOutput = [];
input.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (key != "question1") {
      if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
        questionsOutput.push({ question: key, [item[key].join(",")]: 1 });
      } else {
        questionsOutput.push({ question: key, [item[key]]: 1 });
      }
    }
  });
});
const finalOutput = [...countriesOutput, ...questionsOutput];
console.log(finalOutput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, "item1" count should be 2, I was also stucked there

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of summarizing the input using a dictionary (like Object) and track the duplicates. The "name" of the name/value pair can be uniquely identified by combining the question and answer with some delimiter.

```js
const input = [{
    "question1": "USA",
    "question2": ["item1"],
    "question4": 2
  },
  {
    "question1": "USA",
    "question2": ["item1"],
    "question4": 3
  },
  {
    "question1": "AUS",
    "question2": ["item1", "item2"]
  }
];



//Sum the input to an array which we can easily search for duplciates
var repeatCounter = {};

input.forEach(objItem => {

  Object.keys(objItem).forEach(propItem => {


    //Get the counter and the string
    var s = `${propItem}-${objItem[propItem]}`;
    var c = repeatCounter[s] || 0;

    //Modify it or introduce it if absent
    repeatCounter[s] = c + 1;


  })

})




var output = Object.keys(repeatCounter).map(element => {

  var ret = {'question': element.split('-')[0]}

  ret[element.split('-')[1]] = repeatCounter[element];
  
  return ret;

})


   console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Subtle adjustments such as fortifying the delimiter, converting multiple strings in to array items(as shown in the question) needs to be done on practical grounds.